# Cannot forbid negative numbers from test

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to accept only positive decimal numbers. Here is what I did :

```
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
            var regex = new RegExp(/^\+?\d+,|\.?\d+$/);
            var test = regex.test($("#param_valeur").val());
            if (test == false) {
                $.alert({
                    title: 'Erreur',
                    content: 'Veuillez saisir un nombre !',
                });
            } else {
                $.post({
                    url:"/track/admin/configureSeuilHorsZone",
                    data:$("#frm").serialize(),
                    success:function(data, status, xhr) {
                        $("#george_content").load("/track/welcome");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

But at runtime it accepts negative numbers ! So how to forbid negatiove numbers ?

Comment: we usually check if `number < 0`. Make that `.val()` a number with `parseFloat`

Answer (score 0):

Your regex alternation and pattern are not doing what you think they are, but in any case, here is a regex pattern for matching only positive decimal numbers/integers:

```
^\+?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$
```

If you want to allow for commas in the whole number portion, then use:

```
^\+?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?$
```

Here is an explanation for the second regex pattern:

```
^            from the start of the string
\+?          match an optional leading + sign
\d{1,3}      then match 1 to 3 digits
(?:,\d{3})*  followed by zero or more thousands groups (e.g. ,123)
(?:\.\d+)?   followed by an optional decimal component
$            end of string
```

Comment: Because `1`, `10`, and `100` don't have a comma separator.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Not if used as a thousands separator. But plenty of locale's use comma for decimal and dot for thousands separator. It seems [OP wants to support both as decimal separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57110719/cannot-forbid-negative-numbers-from-test#comment100740940_57110883).

Comment: @Ivar I disagree.  The OP's regex pattern seems to want to allow any number of commas or digits, followed by an _optional_ decimal component, using _only_ dot as the decimal point (a close inspection of the regex will confirm this).

Answer (score 0):

I won't provide you an alternative regex, I will explain you what's going wrong in your example.

You are using the pipe token to join two different regular expressions, they are:

```
 \+?\d+,
```

and

```
 \.?\d+
```

And at first glance it seems correct. The problem is on the way how `^` and `$` work. The "start of line" token (`^`) and "end of line" token (`$`) will be applied only to adjacent regular expressions, not for every regular expression that you separate with pipe.

Because of this, if you insert a negative number, the "second" regular expression will match, since it just says "match everything that contains an optional dot and a sequence of numbers", with no rules about the start of line.

To fix this, just put both the regular expressions in parenthesis, so the "start of line" and the "end of line" will be applied to both:

```
var regex = new RegExp(/^(\+?\d+,|\.?\d+)$/);
console.log(regex.test('-10'));
```

Comment: While this is tremendously helpful for the OP, to make the answer generally useful I'd also include a helpful suggestion for the situation (+1 from me, not sure who downvoted)

Comment: I tested the regex you are suggesting, and it still has problems.  It would match `.123` but not `123.456`, [see the demo](https://regex101.com/r/Mj0y3k/1).

Comment: I think OP meant to do `^\+?\d+(,|\.)?\d+$` (either a comma or dot as decimal separator.

Comment: @Ivar yes. but I wanted to explain what's going on, not provide a final working solution

Answer (score 0):

Why use a regex? Just check if the input is a number or not and check if the value is less than 0.

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
  const value = $("#param_valeur").val()
  if (isNaN(value) || value < 0) {
    console.log('Error')
  } else {
    console.log('Success')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="param_valeur" type="text">
<button id="btn">Check</button>
```

Comment: Doesn't handle values like `"1,000"` as seems to be intended in asker's code.

Comment: You could remove all commas from the input value to fix that. It depends on how OP wants to handle different locales and number formats.

Answer (score 0):

I used this regex : `var regex = new RegExp(/^\+?\d+,?\d*$|^\+?\d+\.?\d*$/);`

thank you all :)